# Which command can be used to configure a router to reject the address for example 192.168.100.0/24 network using the route command?

Tags: command-line, networking

Which  command can be used to configure a router to reject the address for example 192.168.100.0/24 network using the route command

Comment: What kind of router? Is it running Ubuntu? Are you running ``iptables`` yourself on it?

Comment: yeah it's running ubuntu and also yeah i run iptables on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would be just the right answer:

```
route add -net 192.168.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 reject
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the firewall to do so

```
sudo ufw deny from <ip address>
```

Comment: thanks man but what i need is to do it using route command